# Regular Expressions metacharacters, \< and \>, no longer supported in latest Ruby version?

Tags: ruby, regex, word-boundary

When I investigated this in `irb`, I found that the metacharacters, `\<` and `\>`, returns nil when I expected a value. Under the cheatsheet I'm using, these metacharacters are called "start-of-word" and "end-of-word" respectively. But don't they function the same as "word boundaries"?

It seems to hold true for the examples in "Mastering Regular Expression" by Friedl.

```
irb(main):001:0> "this cat is fat" =~ /\bcat\b/
=> 5
irb(main):002:0> "this cat is fat" =~ /\<cat\>/
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> "cat" =~ /\<cat\>/
=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

That's entirely possible. As of Ruby 1.9, Ruby switched to Oniguruma for regular expression parsing. It's possible that prior to 1.9, \< and > were valid.

However, in researching this, I found that they are listed as a specifically GNU addition to the regex language.

Playing with it in [Rubular](http://rubular.com/), which supports running a regex through several different ruby implementations, I couldn't get \< or > to work in any version. \b seems to be the more standard way of specifying a word boundary...

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has always used `\b` for word boundaries, just like Perl and the other Perl-derived flavors (JavaScript, .NET, Python, etc.).  It's only GNU tools like egrep that use `\<` and `\>`.

Is that the [AddedBytes](https://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/) cheat sheet you're using?  It contains several errors, that being one of them.  Elsewhere it says `<` and `>` are metacharacters and you have to use `\<` and `\>` to match them literally; how's that for a Catch-22?